# How to Unpack Each Byte of a 4-byte Int Uniform in WebGL GLSL?

Tags: glsl, webgl

WebGL doesn't support bit wise operation. So I convert my `int` uniform to `float`. Then use dividing and mod to extract each byte.

However, because of the precision issue, converting `int` to `float` loses some precision if my `int` is too big. Is there any elegant solution to deal with this? Currently my idea is only storing 3 bytes in my 4-byte `int` uniform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a 100% clear what you want to do. First, realize that a 32 bit float has 23 bits of mantissa. That's a one less than 3 bytes. Also, your shader might run at less precision, like fp16 or 8.8 fixed point. So the answer to your question is: No.

Take a step back and think about why you want ints in a low end shader. Usually the mod trick was used to pack (and unpack) float values into and rgba bytes texture or framebuffer.

For uniforms it makes little sense. The shader will still run at low (float) precision. So any math you do will run at at most 23bits. And you can supply that just fine as a float uniform.

Comment: I want to pass a 1-byte array to GPU but WebGL doesn't support 1-byte uniform. So I want to pack it into a 4-byte uniform and unpack it in shader.

Comment: Just pass it as a float directly. If it's a lot of bytes, pass it as a texture. You could pass 2 bytes per float uniform, but I really would not rely on it. You can not do more than 2 bytes precisely as floats have only 23bit of mantissa.